# Trouble getting distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table that holds IDs, with a alternate identifier.

```
ID| Alternate
1 | 100000000
1 | 8471
1 | 1248

2 | 578887518
2 | 8415
2 | 3574

3 | 100000000
3 | 1248
```

There are two types of alternate identifiers.. 9 digit, and 4 digit.  Every ID, has a 9 digit alternate, and then up to four different 4 digit ones.

My issue is that the table is not unique.  There exists cases similar to the above example IDs 1 and 3.  There probably also exists situations, although I haven't found one yet, where the 9 digit identifiers match, but there are different 4 digit identifiers..

```
ID | Alternate
5  | 200000000
5  | 1234

6  | 200000000
6  | 4567
```

My goal is to create a table, and pivot on the alternate identifier value, however I'm currently getting two rows for the same user.

Does someone know how I would go about fixing this?
Current code

```
SELECT  ID,  [THCI], [2101] , [2202], [2245] 
FROM          
    (SELECT     
        T1.[ID], 
        T1.[IDENTIFIER],
        CASE WHEN T2.[MAIN_IDENT] IS NULL THEN 'THCI' ELSE T2.[MAIN_IDENT] END AS PIV

    FROM MYTABLE T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T2.[REFNO] = T1.[REFNO]
    WHERE 
        (LEN(T2.[MAIN_IDENT]) = 4 OR T2.[MAIN_IDENT] IS NULL)
        AND (LEN(T1.[IDENTIFIER]) = 4 OR LEN(T1.[IDENTIFIER]) = 9)
    ) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT (MAX([IDENTIFIER]) FOR PIV IN ([THCI], [2245], [2202], [2101],[2345],[2303])) AS MYPIV
```

EDIT:
Expected output would be.  Note also, it's four alternate identifiers, not three.. Doesn't change much though

```
[ID] | [THCI]      | [2245] | [2202] | [2101] | [2345] 
1    | 100000000   | 4817   | 6824   | NULL   | 1587
2    | 845279514   | 2359   | 7847   | 1234   | NULL
3    | 415784521   | 2415   | NULL   | NULL   | 8747
```

Comment: To be honest, your problem seems so specific to me that I would appreciate an example of expected output added to confirm what's been laid out verbally.

Comment: Expected output now added

Comment: Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your table structures and some sample data?

Comment: first set is where I'm at.. Second is what cha has suggested.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac1dc/6

Comment: Is there something wrong with your own solution? If you don't like potential duplicating of THCI (like the 123456321 in your Fiddle example), it should be easy to fix. On the other hand, the query in your Fiddle doesn't output IDs. If it did, it would be clear the duplicates belong to different IDs (and so are not duplicates technically).

Comment: The THCI numbers are meant to be unique, which is my issue

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to retrieve the data omitting the duplicate values it can be done by first retrieving the data for 9-character `IDENTIFIER` (grouped by with MAX(ID)) and then JOINING WITH the same table filtered for 4-character `IDENTIFIER`. So, the inner SELECT statement will look similar to this one (apply PIVOT on it):

```
SELECT 
    IDENT9.ID,
    IDENT9.IDENTIFIER,
    IDENT4.IDENTIFIER
FROM
    (SELECT     
    MAX([ID]) ID, 
    [IDENTIFIER],
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE LEN([IDENTIFIER]) = 9
    GROUP BY [IDENTIFIER]) AS IDENT9
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT     
    MAX([ID]) ID, 
    [IDENTIFIER],
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE LEN([IDENTIFIER]) = 4
    GROUP BY [IDENTIFIER]) AS IDENT4
ON IDENT4.ID = IDENT9.ID
```

The idea here is to have 9-character identifiers and 4-character identifiers in a separate columns. The purpose of IDENT4 and IDENT9 views is to remove the duplicates.

However, if your goal is to fix the database integrity, then you need to think of separating the 9-character and 4-character identifiers in two separate tables. From what you have said I can assume that every ID has one 9-character identifier and at at least one (or more) 4-character identifiers. So, you would create a master table holding 9-character IDs using IDENT9 query as a basis, and a "slave" 4-character ID table. With these tables you would be able to create constraints on the database level enforcing the duplicate checks